# selected all possible immediate children of ng-content

Tags: css, angular

**UPDATE**

**::ng-deep** was used to make it halfway work.

```
:host {
&::ng-deep*:hover {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

it applies the style to the hovered item instead of the entire container,
but also applies it to all of the item's children and children of children.

I tried using `:first-child` instead of `*` but apparently `::ng-deep` is responsible for taking me this many steps deeper.

---

I'm trying to create a template which styles all injected children.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-template',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>,
  styles: [`
    :host {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
  `]
})
export class Template {
}
```

so far it so good, template passes on and accurately styles the content within in.

problem is when I'm trying to pass styling to the content itself, which currently does not reflect anything:

**style.scss:**

```
:host {
  display: flex; // reflected
  flex-direction: column; // reflected
  * { // trying to select any child
    &:hover { 
      background: red; // does not reflect
    }
  }
}
```

I'm passing an array of items in my case:

```
<custom-template>
  <div *ngFor="let item of items">
</custom-template>
```

And I would like to pass on some `:hover` behaviour on any of the children passed to the template

UPDATE:

failed methods:

```
:host {
  &*:hover {
    background: red; // styles the entire array on hover
  }
}
```

Comment: Because it should be `& *`

Comment: thanks for replying, I tried. no go yet...

Answer (score 0):

try out this please it should work.

```
:host:hover { background: red;}
 or
:host(:hover) { background: red;}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. this paints the entire `<template/>` red. I'm trying to get it to paint only the specific hovered element within the template.

Comment: then you should use :host-context something like this :host-context(.parent:hover) {background: red;}

Comment: I want to refrain using any specific selector, aka `.parent`, as the content that is supposed to be injected is dynamic (e.g. `div`, `button` etc). therefore I went for `:host-context(*):hover {...}` and it let me to the same result, entire container painted red

Comment: plus, `:host-context(*:hover) {
    background: red;
  }` makes the entire container painted red, even if I wasn't `hover`ing that specific container

Comment: managed to do it using `&::ng-deep*:hover {...}`. thank you so much for your responses !